# Speakers don't un-mute after muting the audio

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I recently installed Bluedevil on my Fedora 21 XFCE notebook to be able to use my AS-600 bluetooth headphones, and they worked pretty well, the problem now is that whenever I mute the audio by running `amixer set Master toggle -q` I can't un-mute it by running it again, I have to head to the mixer and manually un-mute it by clicking on the small speaker icon under the speaker:

Before "muting":

[image]

In "muted" state:

[image]

After "un-muting":

[image]

As you can see, the `amixer set Master toggle -q` command mutes both the Master and Speaker channels but it only un-mutes the Master channel when run again, I have to note that this didn't happen before installing bluedevil and pulseaudio-bluetooth, and uninstalling them just didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some bug between ALSA and Pulseaudio.

To fix this, set the device flag to pulse:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle -q
```

(source: [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Output_stuck_muted_while_Master_is_toggled))

Comment: I started using pulse (pavucontrol) instead of alsamixer to control the volume and many issues have been gone, but I can confirm that by manually specifying the device flag this issue is solved.